# $Ax=0$ has trivial solution $\implies$ $Ax=b$ has a unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to prove that these three conditions are equivalent.

1. $Ax=0$ has only trivial solution.
2. operator $A$ is invertible.
3. $Ax=B$ has a unique solution.

I proved $1 \implies 2$ and $2 \implies 3$ but I need help writing the proof of $3 \implies 1$. Can you help me with this?

IMO I think this is trivial, but I need help writing it clearly.

Comment: Suppose that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for each $b$.  Now... in particular it has a unique solution for $b=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the assumption that $Ax = b$ has a unique solution, suppose that $Ax = 0$ had a nontrivial solution, i.e. $A\bar{x} = 0$ for some $\bar{x} \neq 0$. Then, assuming $x^*$ is the solution of $Ax = b$:

$$
A(x^* + \bar{x}) = Ax^* + A(\bar{x}) = b + 0 = b
$$
which would show that $Ax = b$ has at least two solutions, a contradiction.

Comment: Cheers! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $A x = b$ has two solutions $x_1,x_2$ or

$$
A x_1 = b\\
A x_2 = b
$$

then by linearity

$$
A(x_1-x_2) = b-b = 0
$$

but the solution for $A(x_1-x_2) = 0$ is $x_1-x_2 = 0\Rightarrow x_1 = x_2$